# How do I create a new ContentDocument Version in apex?

Tags: files, contentversion, contentdocument

I'm getting insufficient privileges error when I try to create a new version for an existing file in apex.

Code used to create new version:

```
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM    ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :parentId LIMIT 1];

        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
            ContentDocumentId = cdl.ContentDocumentId,
            Title = attachmentName,
            PathOnClient = attachmentName,
            ReasonForChange = 'Document replaced by user',
            VersionData = EncodingUtil.Base64Decode(attachmentBody),
            IsMajorVersion = true
        );

        insert contentVersion;
```

Error:
 INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because the user does not have permission to see the `ContentDocument` to which you're trying to attach the file. I suspect the reason for this is that you have `WHERE LinkedEntityId = :parentId LIMIT 1` in your query. If the object (Account, Contact, what have you) identified by `parentId` has more than one file attached to it, that query is going to get you the Id of just one of them, and it may not be the `ContentDocument` you actually intend to be working with.

It's not clear whether or not you're running this code and the code to create the first `ContentVersion` in the same user context, but that's worth confirming. Additionally, even if you find that this works or doesn't work *once*, it's not going to work in production with that `LIMIT` clause in there.

Before focusing on potential code issues, you should also make sure the running user can upload new versions completely through the UI.

Comment: David thanks for your response. I checked if the ContentDocumentId returned by the SOQL points to the right file in system debug and it seems OK. However I noticed the file is missing the 'Upload New Version' link on the detail page that normally appears when I create it using the UI. I created this file using apex below:
      ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
                Title = attachmentName,
                PathOnClient = attachmentName,
                VersionData = EncodingUtil.Base64Decode(attachmentBody),
                IsMajorVersion = true
            );